# find not working correctly in cron

Tags: find, cron

We have a regular job on a server that creates some files in `/tmp` and doesn't delete them after it is done. For reasons I don't want to get into, we can't modify the job to delete the files. So I was thinking to create a cronjob that deletes those files regularly. To not interfere with running jobs, it should delete only files that are older than a day. I came up with the following command:

```
find /tmp/myprefix* -mtime +1 -delete
```

This works just fine if I test it in a terminal so I scheduled it with cron:

```
0 1 * * * find /tmp/myprefix* -mtime +1 -delete
```

Now if this runs at 1 AM, it seems to ignore the `-mtime` parameter and deletes all files starting with `myprefix`, thus interfering with the running job.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

As a remark: Since the job only runs at night, my tests where all performed while no jobs where running. I just checked that the files from last nights finished job remain. Maybe that's the reason and the modifiy time of the file is set in a strange way while the file is still written on?

I know the obvious solution would be to schedule the cleanup during the day but I'm still interested in the cause of my problem.

**EDIT**

According to Kusalanandas suggestion I changed the cron entry for last night to:

```
0 1 * * * find /tmp/myprefix* -mtime +1 -ls > /tmp/find.out
```

The file `/tmp/find.out` is empty this morning. This is expected behaviour since there were no files old enough. But according to past observations, if I had run this with `-delete` the "too young" files would have been deleted.

**EDIT 2**

After the last test I changed the command for the next night to

```
0 1 * * * find /tmp/myprefix* -mtime +2 -delete
```

With the `+2` I was expecting, that none of the files created the night before would be deleted. While those files actually did remain, the files from this night were deleted. Now I'm sure that the `-mtime` check doesn't behave as expected if the file is still written. It remains a mistery, why the `-ls` didn't output anything the night before. Maybe I'll try another run with `-exec` and `ls` for possibly more detail. But I just have one more try before my 2 weeks of holydays :-)

Comment: Can you view the associated log, e.g. via `journalctl -r --unit=cronie.service`?

Comment: As a way of debugging this, make it _not_ delete the files and use `-ls` in place of `-delete`.  Then investigate the output (this would be mailed to the owner of the cronjob if the system is sanely configured) and compare the modification timestamp against the time the job was run.

Comment: @Rastapopoulos there are no entries in the log

Comment: @Kusalananda I've set it up with `-ls` for tonight. Will get back to you tomorrow.

Comment: @Kusalananda see my edit. It's getting stranger...

Comment: If the output is empty, it means `-ls` was not triggered. _That_ means that `-delete` would not have been triggered either.  I think that you either mistyped something the first time around, or that your files were _genuinely_ modified more than a day ago.

Comment: @Kusalananda I would have thought so too. For next night I'm going to change to `-mtime +2` and add the `-delete` again. That should mean that all files existing right now should not be deleted.

Comment: ... unless you hit an edge case where the files were modified exactly on a 24 interval from when the cron job is running (which means it depends on small delays whether they pass the test or not).

Comment: Regarding your second update: You don't have _something else_ deleting files? A cron job run by other means or some other `/tmp`-cleaning system job?

Comment: @Kusalananda we don't have full operational control about that platform. I'd have to ask the service provider. But the reproducable observation is: if I don't let the cronjob delete, we have no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Cron entries only look like another bash line, but are not. Try put your find syntax to separate script and then execute, e.g.:

`echo "find /tmp/myprefix* -mtime +1 -delete" > /my/path/cronscript.sh
chmod 755 /my/path/cronscript.sh`
and edit cron line to:
`0 1 * * * /my/path/cronscript.sh`
Some `chown / chgrp` adjustments can be require as well. Also, if you work under `/etc/crontab` file, additional `username` information will be needed: `0 1 * * * username /my/path/cronscript.sh`

Comment: There's, AFAIK, nothing in the cron job specification of this job that would make it _not_ run as expected.  For example, there are no `%` in the command line, and it's a simple one-command job.